# flutter web - html_editor_enhanced throwing error when try to change the font-family or font size

Tags: flutter, html-editor

### found the answer of the problem

**Here is the code for my Html editor. which is running perfectly, But when I try to change the font size or type, in total whenever I click on any drop down menu it throwing error in web, but working perfectly in Android.**

Update :: I found out that, It's a bug with the package: they have mentioned it there. use this method, solves the problem and works fine.
**The current workaround is to build and/or run your Web app with `flutter run --web-renderer html` and `flutter build web --web-renderer html`.**

```
HtmlEditor(
                controller: controller, //required
                htmlToolbarOptions: const HtmlToolbarOptions(
                  dropdownMenuMaxHeight: 100,
                  dropdownMenuDirection: DropdownMenuDirection.down,
                  dropdownItemHeight: 60,
                ),

                htmlEditorOptions: const HtmlEditorOptions(
                  hint: "Your text here...",
                  autoAdjustHeight: true,
                  spellCheck: true,
                  adjustHeightForKeyboard: true,
                  androidUseHybridComposition: true
                ),
                otherOptions: const OtherOptions(height: 400, decoration: BoxDecoration()),
              ),
```

[This is the image of the HtmlEditor code output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWdxJ.png)

**Whenever I try to change the fontsize or click on any dropdown menu: this error is showing from the
`focus_manager.dart`- file**

```
  // Request that an update be scheduled, optionally requesting focus for the
  // given newFocus node.
  void _markNeedsUpdate() {
    assert(_focusDebug('Scheduling update, current focus is $_primaryFocus, next focus will be $_markedForFocus'));
    if (_haveScheduledUpdate) {
      return;
    }
    _haveScheduledUpdate = true;
    scheduleMicrotask(_applyFocusChange);
  }
```

*These are the images from android*
[These are the images from android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYUSt.jpg)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVnYG.jpg)

but it's not working on flutter web. (not in google chrome or Edge)

.